# How to structure speech recognition code in an executable c# WinForms App?

Tags: c#, winforms, speech-recognition

[link to original code - please look at it first.](http://ellismis.com/2012/03/17/converting-or-transcribing-audio-to-text-using-c-and-net-system-speech/)

I'm not sure how to write this code so that it runs properly. So far my attempt:

The code in the website is using System Speech Recognition from Microsoft to record audio from microphone and turn it into text. Except, I don't know how to format that code on the website properly. The below certainly does not work. I get red underlines everywhere. I'm also not sure how 'event-handler' code is supposed to look like.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Drawing; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Windows.Forms; 
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace SystemSpeechRecognition_winForms
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine _speechRecognitionEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

        _speechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        DictationGrammar _dictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar();

        _speechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(_dictationGrammar);

        _speechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

> ERROR for the four lines
>   This is the error: 
>       .
>   "delegate System.EventHandler"
>   "Represents the method that will handle an event that has no event data"
>   "Error: No overload for 'SpeechRecognized' matches delegate 'System.EventHanndler'

```
        _speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized -= new EventHandler(SpeechRecognized);



        _speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechHypothesized -= new EventHandler(SpeechHypothesizing);


        _speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler(SpeechRecognized);

        _speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechHypothesized += new EventHandler(SpeechHypothesizing);

    }

    private void SpeechHypothesizing(object sender, SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs e)
    {

        ///real-time results from the engine

        string realTimeResults = e.Result.Text;

    }


    private void SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {

        ///final answer from the engine

        string finalAnswer = e.Result.Text;

    }

}
```

Comment: Please be far more specific about what your issue is. Posting a bunch of code and saying "it doesn't work" isn't going to go well here.

Comment: These events are not of type EventHandler.  Just let the compiler figure it out and delete "new EventHandler".

Comment: @HansPassant, I did what you said, ran the code. I guess there is no more errors? But NOTHING is happening. I don't even know if i'm supposed to put that code inside these methods. Did you look at the original link? How do I run the code from the original [link](http://ellismis.com/2012/03/17/converting-or-transcribing-audio-to-text-using-c-and-net-system-speech/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having compilation issues because - to take one of the events as an example - the `SpeechRecognized` event is of type `EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>` and you are attempting to assign it an instance of the non-generic `EventHandler` class.

```
_speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized -= new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(SpeechRecognized);
```

Comment: I changed all those four lines to what you stated above,  I get a new error on for the second and fourth lines. Error: No overload for SpeechHypotheseizing' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler<System.EventHandler<System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>

Comment: Because the [SpeechHypotheseizing event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.speechhypothesized%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is an `EventHandler<SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs>`. Hans is right int the comments that just removing the `new EventHandler` part and letting the compiler figure it out is the normal way of doing things.

Comment: but when i just remove 'new EventHandler' there is no error. But nothing is happening. Would you know why?

Comment: Never used the class, but judging from the [example provided in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.aspx) it could be because you're never calling the `RecognizeAsync` method telling the engine to start processing anything.

Comment: I tried the code that was in the link you gave me ^. There are 3 event handlers in it: LoadGrammarCompleted, SpeechDetected, SpeechRecognized. I made a new console project and copied the code. Didn't change anything. But when I run it, only the "Speech Detected" event is evoked. The city name I am saying into my microphone is not detected. I want the text of what I am saying. But I don't see that.